# Update PostgreSQL table using ssh remote command with shell script

Tags: postgresql, shell

Could you help me, I'm trying to perform an update on a table on PostgreSQL by shell script by sending the remote command externally to the server following my code.

Today I am executing a command to select and it is working, but for update I have a return of failure indicating that the column where I will set the information does not exist.

Executing the form I am displaying, I can extract the result from the execution of the query and display it in the terminal, but to carry out the update I have the following return:

```
result=$(ssh 10.11.12.193 '"(`psql -d totalipdb -U totalip -A -t --command="select host,name,phone_number,active from trunks where id = '$LINHA';"`"');
```

Result: all information returned for select OK.

```
bash: (10.11.12.163|URA Desenvolvimento|sip_ura|f: command not found.
```

I need to run updates too, can you help me?

```
result=$(ssh 10.11.12.193 '"(`psql -d totalipdb -U totalip -A -t --command="UPDATE trunks SET active = 'f' WHERE id = '55';"`"');

ERROR:  column "f" does not exist
LINHA 1: UPDATE trunks SET active = f WHERE id = 55;
```

Comment: You have to fix your quoting, `f` arrives at the database without the single quotes, so it is thought to be a column name. Either use a "here document" to escape from quoting hell or use `FALSE` without quotes.

Comment: sorry, for incorrect quote i try remove  " " and ' ' this result: ERROR:  column "f" does not exist
LINHA 1: update trunks set active = f where id = 22;

Comment: Of course. I said it: either write `FALSE` or use a here document.

Comment: GREAT! it works perfectly!!  thank you so much  please close thread five *****